# Samsung Galaxy S2 recites any actions that I do. How to turn it off?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, accessibility, talk-back

My phone won't stop talking. It won't let me scroll or see other settings, I've tried to go back the way I did and turn it off, but I can't scroll down or up. I have to double click on applications to open them everything I touch. It speaks to me what I touched. How can I reset that?

Comment: Did you try AndrewT's answer after his edit?

Answer (score 1):

There is a big chance you turned on [TalkBack accessibility option](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/faq/FAQ00046058/48858/SCH-R760IBAUSC) by accident. You may want to turn off to fix this "issue".

> *Enable or disable accessibility services.*
>
> 1. From the Home screen, touch **Applications** [image] > **Settings** > **Accessibility** .
> 2. Touch **Accessibility** to toggle a checkmark.
> 3. Touch **TalkBack** to toggle a checkmark. When enabled, recites menu options, application titles, contacts, and other items when scrolling and making selections.
>
> If an Attention prompt appears, touch **OK** to continue or **Cancel** to exit.

<sub>(copied with slight modification)</sub>

To scroll when TalkBack is active, use 2 fingers when scrolling. From [Google Support](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6007100?hl=en)

> Tip: To scroll across screens, use two fingers along the screen.